# what means starting and Maintaining voltage in this specification?

Tags: high-voltage, circuit-design

i want to drive a pneumatic ejector(open and close), is specifications in following:

```
Starting Voltage : 100V
Maintaining voltage : 12V
Resistance Value :18Ω
Frequency(Hz)：800-1000
Maximum instantaneous power : 200W
Standby power : 3W
```

what means starting voltage and Maintaining voltage?
do is correct that 100 volt is for on and 12 volt for off ? if yes what is best circuit for it?
do is below circuit appropriate ?
[Solenoid Driving Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/solenoid-driving-circuit)

Comment: Means it's a solenoid. To start, you need to build a magnetic field across a gap. Then the gap closes so you need much less power to hold it in place. And 0V to let it turn off again. (Not necessarily cylindrical)

Comment: thanks: Brian Drummond , namely: it is a cylindrical coil of wire acting as a magnet when carrying electric current ? what is your The proposed circuit for drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below circuite is appropriate for it:

[image]