# Solenoid 12 V control with Arduino

Tags: arduino, 12v, 5v

I have some 12 V solenoids and I want to control them via Arduino, but Arduino outputs a maximum 9 V voltage through the Arduino jack input, and the voltage on Arduino pins is only 5 V, so how do I control some solenoids with an Arduino pin which is only 5 V?

Comment: You'd probably consider using a transistor (resistor+NPN BJT or else an NFET) and a diode or a diode+zener to cope with stored energy when turning it off.

Comment: Look at the many questions which consider the use of a transistor or FET low side switch to control a solenoid, relay coil, high power lamp, etc.  And yes, as mentioned, an inductive load will need a catch diode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arduino Uno with 12V pump: transistor or optocoupler+12V relay?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57899/arduino-uno-with-12v-pump-transistor-or-optocoupler12v-relay)

Comment: @AloisiusMardiyanto What kind of "solenoids"? Relays? Please note that, even if the "solenoids" were 5V or 9V, you should never try to control them directly with Arduino (unless the relays was mounted themselves in digitally controlable modules). Basically, what you need to do is connect one of the 5V pins of Arduino to a control device (the best option seems to be a transistor) that will turn the 12V on, in order to power your solenoids. Besides the excelent link from the comment above, this is a trivial circuit that can be easily googled...

Comment: Just google "mosfet solenoid driver" and look at the images...

Comment: Or here on stack exchange https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/solenoid-driving-circuit . R1 typically 4k7,  R2 typically 100k , the catch diode is schottky  e.g 1n5602. If using a 3.3v cpu, you will need a MOSFET with logic level gate drive, it will typically have an L in the partnumber.